# argument "second_str" is missing with no default

Tags: r

I have written a function which finds the intersection between two strings. I want to use this function in apply and find out all the intersections in the given data frame. I am using below code.

Function:-

```
common <- function(first_str,second_str)
  {
    a <- unlist(strsplit(first_str," "))
    b <- unlist(strsplit(second_str," "))
    com <- intersect(a,b)
    return((length(com)/length(union(a,b)))*100)
  }
```

Data frame:-

```
str1 <- c("One Two Three","X Y Z")
str2 <- c("One Two Four", "X Y A")

df <- data.frame(str1, str2)
```

When use apply I get **argument "second_str" is missing with no default** error

```
apply(df, 1, common)
```

Could you please help me out with the solution?

Comment: Try `mapply(common,df$str1,df$str2)`

Answer (score 2):

`apply()` will only pass a single vector to the function you provide. With `margin=1` it will call your function once per each row with a single vector containing all the values for the "current" row. It will not split up those values into multiple parameters to your function.

You could instead re-write your function to

```
common2 <- function(x) {
    first_str <- x[1]
    second_str <- x[2]
    a <- unlist(strsplit(first_str," "))
    b <- unlist(strsplit(second_str," "))
    com <- intersect(a,b)
    return((length(com)/length(union(a,b)))*100)
}
```

Although that doesn't scale well for multiple parameters. YOu could also use `Map` or `mapply` to iterate over multiple vectors at a time

If your original function you can do

```
with(df, Map(common, str1, str2))
```